# Random glitches

Tags: rendering

> I keep getting these random white glitches whenever my object is on the rendered option

[image: Text]

Comment: Hi, could you give a bit more detail if you can, to help make it easier to answer? Without detail, it can be very hard to work out what is going on, unless someone else has had this exact problem before. Try saying if it is still there in a final render, what render engine you are using, or other details that you may have figured out or think may be important. (sorry if this comment is a bit long)

Comment: I have had a look at the image and the only thing i could suggest is to make the sample count higher maybe?? Another thing that could be useful to know is if this happens in all projects or just this one?

Comment: An issue with your graphic hardware. Try updating your driver and use latest Blender

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens with me also , you can easily fix this if you are in eevee(You are obviously in eevee) , go to render settings and switch on Screen Space Reflections , This will make these Pixelations disappear , or you can simply switch to cycles